# How to practically rename tables and columns in PostgreSQL on a production system?

Tags: postgresql

It often happens that the original name something is given is not the best name. Maybe requirements shifted slightly, or maybe as time went on, a better understanding of the concept being represented developed. Sometimes one name is used in developing a feature, but testing with real users reveals that a better name is needed, and it'd be nice to have the names for things in the DB match the names used in the UI.

PostgreSQL lets you rename tables and columns via `alter table`, but often this isn't feasible in production without significant downtime. If existing clients are using the old name, you can't just yank it out from under them.

I was hoping there was some way to "add a name" to a table or column, so that `old_name` and `new_name` will both work, and then at a later time remove the old name. Then a name migration could work like this:

- add `new_name`
- modify all clients to use `new_name` instead of `old_name`
- once all clients have been updated, remove `old_name`

Is there a way to do this? If not, is there a recommended procedure for renaming a column while minimizing downtime? How about a table?

Comment: Use a [VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) with the columns renamed. This will be simple for read only tables. For tables that are going to have INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE read "Updatable View" section of link.

Comment: A VIEW that only renames the table and column names is automatically updatable.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If I want to rename a column but not the table it resides in, is it possible to use a view?

Comment: Yes, read the view link I posted.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Can you please clarify? I'm probably missing something, but I've read that link and I don't see a straightforward way to add an updatable column to an existing table with a view. If I attempt to `create or replace view my_table as select *, old_name as new_name from my_table from my_table` I get "ERROR:  "my_table" is not a view", and without the `or replace` I get "ERROR:  relation "my_table" already exists".

Comment: My mistake. Per link: "The name of the view must be distinct from the name of any other view, table, sequence, index or foreign table in the same schema." So this will only work if you create the view in a different schema when using the same name for the view as the table.

Answer (score 17):

Some recipes for renaming tables and/or columns in a production system that seem to work. However, I've only tested these on a small test database, not on a large production system. Renaming and view creation are both supposed to be very fast, though.

### Renaming a table

1. Rename the table, and temporarily add an updatable view with the old name:

   ```sql
   begin;
       alter table old_table_name rename to new_table_name;

       create view old_table_name as
           select * from new_table_name;
   commit;
   ```
2. Migrate clients to use the new table name.
3. Once all clients are migrated, drop the view:

   ```sql
   drop view old_table_name;
   ```

### Renaming columns without renaming the table

Renaming a column without renaming the table is a bit more complicated,
because we can't have a view shadow a table (apparently).

1. Rename the column(s), temporarily rename the table, and add an updatable
   view that adds the old name for the column with the table's correct name:

   ```sql
   begin;
       alter table my_table rename column old_column_name to new_column_name;

       alter table my_table rename to my_table_tmp;

       create view my_table as
           select *, new_column_name as old_column_name
           from my_table_tmp;

   commit;
   ```
2. Migrate clients to use the new column name.
3. Once all clients are migrated, drop the view, rename the table back:

   ```sql
   begin;
       drop view my_table;

       alter table my_table_tmp rename to my_table;
   commit;
   ```

### Renaming a table and some of its columns simultaneously

1. Rename the table and columns, and temporarily add an updatable view with the old name and old columns:

   ```sql
   begin;
       alter table old_table_name
           rename to new_table_name;

       alter table new_table_name
           rename column old_column_name to new_column_name;

       create view old_table_name as
           select *, old_column_name as new_column_name
           from new_table_name;
   commit;
   ```

   Instead of `select *, old_column_name as new_column_name`, it might be better to only have
   the original set of columns, so clients have to migrate to the new table
   name to get the new column names:

   ```sql
   create view old_table_name as
       select
           unchanged_name1,
           unchanged_name2,
           ...
           old_column_name as new_column_name
       from new_table_name;
   ```
2. Migrate clients to use the new table and column names.
3. Once all clients are migrated, drop the view:

   ```sql
   drop view old_table_name;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianKlaver, for your suggestion to use a view.

Comment: I used this approach to rename a column and it worked very well.

Comment: Is it possible to delete fields in a similar way?

Comment: @Tvaroh dropping a column is much simpler. 1. Change all clients to stop reading it. 2. Make the column nullable or give it a default value (if it doesn't already have one). 3. Change all clients to no longer write to it. 4. Drop the column: `alter table table_name drop column column_name`.

Comment: This answer is excellent!